# Yii2: checkboxList doesn't show ArrayDataProvider

Tags: php, arrays, yii2, checkboxlist

I want to use a `checkboxList` to show data from a data provider.

My view file:

```
$offices = Offices::findMyOffices();
echo Html::checkboxList('name', [], $offices);
```

My model file:

```
public static function findMyOffices()
{    
    $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => 'SELECT id_office ...'
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

But the view shows me the checkbox list with the **sql query** instead of the **sql query's results**:

[image: My checkbox list showing my select query instead of results]

Comment: Did you tried to read documentation? `allModels` should be list of models, not SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it `using sqlDataProvider`:

View:

```
$offices = Offices::findMyOffices();        
echo Html::checkboxList('name', [], ArrayHelper::map($offices, 'id_office', 'name_office'));
```

Model:

```
public static function findMyOffices()
{    
    $dataProvider = new sqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => 'SELECT id_office ...'
    ]);

    return $dataProvider->getModels();
}
```

Comment: Why you're using data provider instead of `ActiveRecord::findBySql()`?

Comment: It is easier for me to use queries or I don't know how to use ActiveRecord::findBySql()  :)

Comment: Usually it does not make sense to use data providers in such context - main benefit of data provider is support for sorting and pagination, and you probably don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayDataProvider needs an array of items. you can add ->asArray() to your activequery.

```
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => [['id' => 1, 'title' => 'xxx, ...], ...],
    ]);
```

my favorite for fetching data for a dropdown is:

```
MyModel::find()->select('name', 'id')->indexBy('id')->column()
```